# Barracuda Message Archiver 501 5.5.4 Invalid arguments - new Exchange-Server

Tags: email, exchange, archive, barracuda, exchange-2019

after a Migration to Exchange 2019 I have problems to send mails to the barracuda message archiver from the new servers. The mails are forwarded via a send connector.

I allowed the new ip-addresses as trusted smtp servers in the barracuda.

Here is the log:

Working old exchange:

```
2021-11-22T09:19:24.126Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,1,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,+,,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,2,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,"220 barracuda650.mydomain.local ESMTP Barracuda; Mon, 22 Nov 2021 01:19:24 -0800 (PST)",
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,3,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,>,EHLO exchange1.mydomain.local,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,4,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,"250-barracuda650.mydomain.local Hello exchange1.mydomain.local [192.168.1.25], pleased to meet you",
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,5,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,250-PIPELINING,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,6,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,250-AUTH LOGIN,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,7,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,250 HELP,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,8,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,*,,sending message with RecordId 75299366633531 and InternetMessageId <cb2eda02-e1ed-4c91-b69b-04db09a6678b@journal.report.generator>
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,9,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,>,MAIL FROM:<>,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,10,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,>,RCPT TO:<bma_journaling@bma.int>,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.142Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,11,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,250 Sender <> OK,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.204Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,12,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,250 Recipient <bma_journaling@bma.int> OK,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.204Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,13,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,>,DATA,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.204Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,14,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.204Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,15,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,250 Ok: queued as mailksU751,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.220Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,16,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,>,QUIT,
2021-11-22T09:19:24.220Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,17,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,<,"221 barracuda650.mydomain.local Goodbye exchange1.mydomain.local, closing connection",
2021-11-22T09:19:24.220Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF6965A9813,18,192.168.1.25:12433,192.168.1.100:25,-,,Local
```

Not working new exchange:

```
2021-11-22T09:00:27.707Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,0,,192.168.1.100:25,*,SendRoutingHeaders,Set Session Permissions
2021-11-22T09:00:27.707Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,1,,192.168.1.100:25,*,,attempting to connect
2021-11-22T09:00:27.708Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,2,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,+,,
2021-11-22T09:00:27.720Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,3,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,<,"220 spg-exchange-01.mydomain.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 22 Nov 2021 10:00:26 +0100",
2021-11-22T09:00:27.720Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,4,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,>,EHLO exchangenew1.mydomain.local,
2021-11-22T09:00:27.722Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,5,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,<,"250  barracuda650.mydomain.local Hello exchangenew1.mydomain.local [192.168.1.35], pleased to meet you SIZE 157286400 PIPELINING 8BITMIME BINARYMIME PIPELINING 8BITMIME HELP",
2021-11-22T09:00:27.722Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,6,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,*,,sending message with RecordId 382252091379 and InternetMessageId <31d39648-f849-4127-99a7-c7cb755250cd@journal.report.generator>
2021-11-22T09:00:27.722Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,7,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,>,MAIL FROM:<> SIZE=10033,
2021-11-22T09:00:27.722Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,8,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,>,RCPT TO:<bma_journaling@bma.int>,
2021-11-22T09:00:27.723Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,9,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,<,250 2.1.0 Sender OK,
2021-11-22T09:00:32.716Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,10,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,<,501 5.5.4 Invalid arguments,
2021-11-22T09:00:32.718Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,11,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,>,RSET,
2021-11-22T09:00:32.718Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,12,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,*,,sending message with RecordId 382252091384 and InternetMessageId <c98704ce-9d42-4490-96f5-411b0e0d12c2@journal.report.generator>
2021-11-22T09:00:32.718Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,13,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,>,MAIL FROM:<> SIZE=27195 BODY=7BIT,
2021-11-22T09:00:32.718Z,BMA Journal Contact Send Connector,08D9ACF06C44EF50,14,192.168.1.35:40612,192.168.1.100:25,>,RCPT TO:<bma_journaling@bma.int>,
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any difference in configurations between old exchange connector and the new exchange connector?

I have compared these 2 logs and I have found that sender is ok, this issue maybe occur to recipient side, could you check the configuration in Barracuda Message Archiver side since I'm not familiar with Barracuda.

Could you run [Get-MessageTrackingLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-messagetrackinglog?view=exchange-ps) to check more details on message delivery status?